# SQL Server Row_number over order by results in invalid column name

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
fld_Id ... ... ... ... ... ... fld_ConsDateTime ... ... ...
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                             2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 
2                             2017-01-02 00:00:00.000
... ... ... .. ..... .. .. . . . .....................
```

And so on.. I generate a query like this and works perfectly fine as expected

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 180 , fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE) AS fld_ConsDate, 
    SUM(fld_EnergyTotalIndexValue) AS fld_ConsumptionValue , 
    MIN(fld_ConsDateTime) AS fld_ConsStartDateTime , 
    MAX(fld_ConsDateTime) AS fld_ConsEndDateTime , 
    MAX(fld_Id) AS fld_Id   
FROM 
    tbl_EM_DeviceEnergyHourlyConsumption  
WHERE
    fld_ConsDateTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*(fld_TZAM) + 180, N'2017-07-18 00:00:00') AND 
    fld_ConsDateTime < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*(fld_TZAM) + 180, N'2017-08-17 00:00:00')
GROUP BY 
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 180 , fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE)
```

In the browser, user can click to a field and sort the records. After user clicks the query I generate (which I only include `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fld_ConsDate asc) AS RN`) populates an error

> Invalid column name 'fld_ConsDate'

My code:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 180, fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE) AS fld_ConsDate, 
    SUM(fld_EnergyTotalIndexValue) AS fld_ConsumptionValue, 
    MIN(fld_ConsDateTime) AS fld_ConsStartDateTime, 
    MAX(fld_ConsDateTime) AS fld_ConsEndDateTime, 
    MAX(fld_Id) AS fld_Id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fld_ConsDate ASC) AS RN
FROM
    tbl_EM_DeviceEnergyHourlyConsumption  
WHERE
    fld_ConsDateTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*(fld_TZAM) + 180, N'2017-07-18 00:00:00') AND 
    fld_ConsDateTime < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*(fld_TZAM) + 180, N'2017-08-17 00:00:00')
GROUP BY 
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 180 , fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE)
```

What seems to be the problem? Any tips?

Comment: not sure of the total problem,wrap your query in a cte like below and do the rest..`with cte as (your query) select* from cte`

Comment: @FreshPro shouldn't it be ROW_NUMBER() (Order by fld_ConsDateTime) AS RN

Comment: @SteveFord ROW_NUMBER() must have an OVER clause

Comment: @TheGameiswar I didn't understand your solution

Comment: i was saying `fld_ConsDate` this being a alias, you can't refer it in same select,try using a cte

Comment: @FreshPro I agree it should have an OVER clause my main point is that you have the wrong field name in your ORDER BY i.e. fld_ConsDate rather than fld_ConsDateTime!